# google sheets, array formulas

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

So I have a spreadsheet here. it's just an example.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-K8La5G2Gr1h_5_l72nuWLv-OGHETY9CqN66RiZ2Rro/edit?usp=sharing

The goal is to track my budget.

Column U: List of expenses
Column V: Prices of expenses in KRW. 
Column X: same list of expenses
Column Y: Prices of expenses in USD

I know to convert KRW to USD I can use the formula 
=V6:V*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:KRWUSD")
because i want to have it start from v6:v since I have the total there. I can apply it to each cell i click on or the whole column, but the whole column doesn't work since I have data written in Y4 and Y5.

The same goes to see if I type out what the expense is for, for example if I type in "restaurant" on U8, "restaurant" will automatically print on X8. The same problem arises in that if i use =arrayformula(U6:U) then it won't work since I have data in columns X4 and X5.

Columns L, M, N, O, P and Q are what I want it to look like but I have to copy and paste for columns L and O. and have to individually select the cells, copy and paste the formula =M7:M*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:KRWUSD")
I'm just trying to cut down on time where I can just input the original item name and cost in the appropriate column and the other 2 columns where the conversion happens will just automatically occur without having to select new cells and copy and paste the formulas

Answer (score 0):

You're right - you need `ARRAYFORMULA` but it needs some control otherwise it will copy down the column into every available cell. So you also want `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` to limit the number of rows and columns (in your case, just rows) that display the formula.

Cell Y6: `=array_constrain(arrayformula(round(V6:V*googlefinance("CURRENCY:KRWUSD"),2)),21,1)`
The array is `V6:V`; it multiplies the value of the conversion, and rounds it to 2 decimal places.
The formula is constrained to display in 21 rows (the depth of your table) and just one column.

Cell W6: `=array_constrain(arrayformula(round(Z6:Z/googlefinance("CURRENCY:KRWUSD"),2)),21,1)`
Identical to Cell Y6, except that 1) the array = Z6:Z, and 2) it divides the US dollar amount by the conversion rate.

Two other cells to note:
Cell V5: `=D15-sum(V6:W26)`
Cell Y5: `=G15-sum(Y6:Z26)`
These both sum the respective currency columns.

The table would look like this:

---

[image]